# How to get custome token in PHTML magento 2

Tags: customer, magento2.3, phtml, customer-session

I need to add products in the cart using rest api in javascript.

Code is below:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
  "cartItem": {
    "sku": "240-LV08",
    "qty": 1,
    "quote_id": "4"
  }
});

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "http://host/rest/V1/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/items");
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization bearer", "wew3dfdfsaffff");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");

xhr.send(data);
```

Here just I need to pass user token by the customer session in PHTML file.

How to get customer token in phtml using object manager.

Comment: are you using the API on your local server? then you don't need to pass the token. especially not the postman token

Comment: sorry I have edited my question pls check this. I don't need postman token but I need customer token to post items in cart either it's local or server..But I am working in AWS @PhilippSander

Comment: you do not need the token when commincating to your webapi! the session is used for authentication.

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-session.html

Comment: I have tried the above in my phtml when customer is logged in but I get customer is not authorized error